# A string that must be exactly one name and another that must be exactly zero or one name

Tags: c#

I have a code below where the first and last name strings have to be exactly one name and the middle name must be exactly zero or one name.. Do any of you guys in here have any idea how to do this? Thank you in advance!

```
public enum Gendertype { Male, Female };
public class Player
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string ShortNationality { get; set; }
    public Gendertype Gender { get; set; }

    public Player(string fn, string mn, string ln, DateTime dob, string n, string sn, Gendertype g)
    {
        FirstName = fn;
        MiddleName = mn;
        LastName = ln;
        DateOfBirth = dob;
        Nationality = n;
        ShortNationality = sn;
        Gender = g;
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Player person1 = new Player("Rafael" + "\n", "" + "\n", "Nadal" + "\n", new DateTime(1986, 06, 03), "Spanish" + "\n", "ES" + "\n", Gendertype.Male);
        Console.WriteLine("Player 1: \n First name = {0} Middle name = {1 } Last name = {2} Date of birth = {3:yyyy/MM/dd} \n Nationality = {4} Short name nationality = {5} Gender = {6}", person1.FirstName, person1.MiddleName, person1.LastName, person1.DateOfBirth, person1.Nationality, person1.ShortNationality, person1.Gender);
        //Nedenstående aldersudregner er taget fra Bob Tabors C# kurser
        DateTime DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("1986/06/03");
        TimeSpan myAge = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateOfBirth);
        Console.WriteLine(" Age = " + myAge.TotalDays / 365 + "\n" + "\n");
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you just looking to check if a string has a value?  Like `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`?

Comment: What do you mean by `exactly one name` and `zero or one name` ?

Comment: One name you mean that `FirstName` contains one word?

Comment: No I mean when let's say the first name is called, this players name has to be exactly one name. It can't be zero or two or more names. Exactly one. Is there any way to do this. Where you will get an error in the cmd.exe if the name is more than one name?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten exactly!

Comment: @Copsiva: Define the rules which identify something as "exactly one name".  Also, obligatory link: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: What if somebody's last name is two words? I had a friend who's last name was like "Saint Cloud"

Comment: So your entire name has between either two or three words, right?

Comment: Just to add a little to the Sunday fun: Do count hyphenated names as one word or as two words... ;)

Answer (score 0):

For `FirstName` and `LastName` you can split on `' '` and see that the count is 1.

```
bool valid = fn.Split(' ').Length == 1
```

And for the `MiddleName` let it be also null or empty:

```
bool valid = string.InNullOrEmpty(mn) || mn.Split(' ').Length == 1
```

You can add `.Trim` if you think a space slipped into one of the names in the beginning or end.

```
bool validFN = fn.Trim().Split(' ').Length == 1
bool validMN = string.InNullOrEmpty(mn) || mn.Trim().Split(' ').Length == 1
```

Comment: People with spaces in their names aren't allowed to use this application?

Comment: That's according to the OP, see the comments

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Split` for this:

```
var names = "Rafael Nadal".Split();
foreName = names[0];
if(names.Length == 2)
{
    surName = names[1];
}
else if (names.Length == 3)
{
    surName = names[2];
    middleName = names[1];
}
else
    throw new ArgumentException("Wrong number of arguments");
```

However if your input is delimited by another character such as a comma, you have to use the overload of `Split` that expects a character as parameter.